# query return a value based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a table where I save the following data:
id - autoincrement
token - a random generated token
when - a timestamp of the moment when the token has been generated

I have a php page where I `POST` the token value. On that page I am building a query that will perform two checks:

- the token exists
- the token has been created less than 24 hours ago

What I want to do is combine the two conditions in a single query and have as response:

- the id if both the conditions are met;
- an error that the token doesn't exists;
- an error that the token exists but was created more than 24 hours ago.

I know how to check for each of the conditions separately with for example to check if the token exists (examples are simplified but in the real life **i am using prepared statements**):

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE token='$token';
```

or if I know the token exists and I want to see if the token was created less than 24 hours ago:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE token='$token' AND when > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)  //untested
```

How do I combine everything in a single query? So that the query will return id/'no token'/'expired' alternatively? I am not that good with mysql to build it myself unfortunately

Comment: when is a column name?

Comment: @P.Salmon the real column name is token_creation_date but for sake of simplicity I put here when

Comment: Is the token column unique?

Comment: yes sir. There will be just one token at most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want 1 row returned in any case, even if the token does not exist in the table.
You can do this with aggregation and a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN MAX(id) IS NULL THEN 'no token'
    WHEN MAX(timestamp) < NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR THEN 'expired'
    ELSE MAX(id)   
  END
FROM table 
WHERE token = '$token'
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3f44c7cae60dd7a1df066d731836d39a).

Comment: max even if the query is returning only a row?

Comment: With MAX() (or MIN()) it is guaranteed that you will get 1 row in any case.